# How to bind List<class> object to gridview

Tags: asp.net

below is my code

```
    List<test> Students = new List<test>(){
    new test() { name = "Jack", imgpath = "15", Des = "100" },
    new test() { name = "Smith", imgpath = "15", Des = "101" },       
    new test() { name = "Smit", imgpath = "1", Des = "102" }
};
GridView1.DataSource = Students;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and my class is:

```
public class test
{
    public string name;
    public string imgpath;
    public string Des;  
 }
```

but it gives me error "A field or property with the name 'name' was not found on the selected data source."

So how to solve it. I do not know what is wrong in  my code.

Thanks

Comment: You need to paste code from ASPX page for Gridview declaration.

Comment: are you using Eval in Gridview. if so, make sure fields name.
 <%# Eval("name") %>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public string name { get; set };
public string imgpath { get; set };
public string Des { get; set };
```

Comment: Because I had the same issue a while ago, and this solved it for me.

Comment: I have taken my vote back, but not really sure this would help

Comment: I have checked this thing and its wroking for me.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to fields is not possible, like stated, use properties instead.

I see you are using ASP.net and can't find anything about its binding at the moment, but I think it is very well explained for WPF, guess microsoft has the same thought for ASP.NET. 
See the link below for the explanation off WPF binding options.

Fields are not a part of the binding source specification:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx